# Error: value cassandraFormat is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Checking the repo on github I see `cassandraFormat` [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/cassandra/package.scala). My import statement is not throwing an exception:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._

df.write
    .cassandraFormat("keyspace", "table")
    .save()

<console>:34: error: value cassandraFormat is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
```

`cassandraFormat` is not available under `df.write` but it is under `spark.read`.

I am using Spark 2.1.1. And my spark-shell is invoked by:

```
spark-shell --master spark://10.0.0.115:7077 --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0,datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.6-s_2.11
```

---

Edit:

I did realise that `cassandraFormat` was basically an alias for `.format().options()`. However a different error was returned:

```
df.write
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .options(Map("table" -> "standard_feed", "keyspace" -> "testing"))
      .save()

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.createRelation
    (Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode;Lscala/collection/
        immutable/Map;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/sources/
        BaseRelation;
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:518)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not so sure about `cassandraFormat` but saving a dataframe to a cassandra table can easiest be done in the following way:

```
df.write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> "table_name", "keyspace" -> "keyspace_name"))
  .save()
```

About the error message you received:

I think the error message you get is due to a version mismatch. You use spark 2.1.1 and cassandra-connector version 1.6.6. For spark 2.1.x you need to use version 2.0 of the cassandra-connector, see table [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility) for a full list of the version compatibilities.

Comment: If you are using AWS GLUE 3.0  working jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/3.0.0/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.0.0.jar